# Скачивание файла по FTP

Tags: php, ftp

Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться со скачиванием файла по FTP:

```
$host = "линк";
$connect = ftp_connect($host);
$user = "юзер";
$password = "пароль";
$res = ftp_login($connect,$user,$password) or die("error");
$get_file = "export.json";
$save_file = "export.json";
ftp_get($connect,$get_file,$save_file,FTP_BINARY);
```

На локалке файл загружается на ура, а вот на хост - нет. Может быть, нужно какие-то права на файл выставить?

Comment: Какие сообщения об ошибках выводит PHP?

Comment: Warning: ftp_get(export.json): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/www/art/data/www/линк/admin/templates/api.php on line 17 Warning: ftp_get(): Error opening export.json in /var/www/art/data/www/линк/admin/templates/api.php on line 17 Это походу права на файл не выставлены?

Answer (score 1):

Для скачивания файла по FTP, у этого файла должны быть проставлены права на чтение для пользователя от имени которого осуществляется доступ (в вашем случае `юзер`).